# How to redirect to other image If the URL is not valid?

Tags: php

I need the code to check if the URL is valid or not,

And if not, to refer the URL to another image URL.

```
<?php
$url = "https://scontent.ftlv2-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-0/p240x240/12140762_1159067420823544_4471328164031495581_n.jpg";
header('Location: $url);
```

Backup Image:

```
http://www.qygjxz.com/data/out/114/5095827-image.jpg
```

Comment: You can try `filter_var()` with `FILTER_VALIDATE_URL` parameter

Comment: $url shoud stand without quotes is that the case at your code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you use this snippet?

```
<?php 
    if(isset($url) && filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)){
      //show image
    }else{
       // header($other url); //redirect back
    }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

you have image path then you should check image like this. for more details about `file_exists` read [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php)

also i mention that error in `header` function `missing quotes`. i fixed this error

```
if(file_exists('https://scontent.ftlv2-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-0/p240x240/12140762_1159067420823544_4471328164031495581_n.jpg')) {
    header('Location: '.$url);
    }else{
      .........
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your are checking image exist or not! you can use [getimagesize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php).

Example:

```
$url = "https://scontent.ftlv2-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-0/p240x240/12140762_1159067420823544_4471328164031495581_n.jpg";
$url2 = "http://www.qygjxz.com/data/out/114/5095827-image.jpg"
if (@getimagesize($url)) {
   header('Location:'. $url);
} else {
  header('Location:'. $url2);
}
```